# ListView c EditText. Редактирование и сохранение значений.

Tags: android, listview, adapter

Здравствуйте. 
Есть ListView, с такой разметкой элемента списка:
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Title"
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cbMark"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spType"
        android:entries="@array/journal_types"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cbMark"
        android:checked="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/etMark"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cbMark"
        android:numeric="integer"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/etDescription"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="@string/description"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spType"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Сделал Custom Adapter, в котором заполняю список из Map.
Стоит задача, при изменении значений, допустим в EditText, перезаписывать их в Map (потому что когда элемента уходит за экран, значения сбрасываются).
Со Spinner разобрался. А как узнать какой EditText был изменён не могу понять, Использую TextWatcher. Код Адаптера:

```
public class EditMarksJournalAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private final Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<Map<String, String>> results;
    private Context ctx;
    private int pos;

LayoutInflater lInflater;
private ViewHolder viewHolder;
private ViewHolder holder;

public EditMarksJournalAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<Map<String, String>> data) {

    results = data;
    activity = a;
    lInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}
public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView tvTitle;
    public EditText etDescription;
    public EditText etMark;
    public Spinner spType;
    public CheckBox cbMark;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return results.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    return results.get(position);
}

public Object getAppName(int position) {

    return results.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return position;
}

public Context getContext() {
    return ctx;
}

public ArrayList<Map<String, String>> getData() {
    return results;
}

public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    pos = position;
    View v = view;
    if (v == null) {
        v = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.marks_edit_list_item, null);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.spType = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spType);
        viewHolder.tvTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        viewHolder.etDescription = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.etDescription);
        viewHolder.etMark = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.etMark);
        viewHolder.cbMark = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.cbMark);

        viewHolder.etMark.setTag(position);
        viewHolder.etDescription.setTag(position);
        viewHolder.cbMark.setTag(position);
        viewHolder.spType.setTag(position);

    } else {
        v = view;
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }

    if (results.get(position).get("type") != null) {
        viewHolder.spType.setSelection(Integer.parseInt(results.get(position).get("type")));
    } else viewHolder.spType.setSelection(0);
    viewHolder.spType.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                   View itemSelected, int selectedItemPosition, long selectedId) {
            results.get((Integer) parent.getTag()).put("type", String.valueOf(selectedItemPosition));
        }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
    viewHolder.tvTitle.setText(results.get(position).get("title"));

    if (results.get(position).get("description") != null)
        viewHolder.etDescription.setText(results.get(position).get("description"));
    viewHolder.etDescription.setFocusable(true);

    if (results.get(position).get("mark") != null)
        viewHolder.etMark.setText(results.get(position).get("mark"));
    viewHolder.etDescription.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });

    viewHolder.etMark.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
   return v;
}
```

В TextWatcher в методе public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) Я должен как-то получить позицию элемента списка, в котором находится изменяемый EditText, но не знаю как.
Помогите разобраться или, если я совсем не так делаю, направить в нужном направлении. Заранее Спасибо!

Comment: Эм. Так у вас же есть `position`, который вы получаете параметром в `getView()`.

Comment: position возвращает позицию последнего созданного или заполненного элемента, а не которого в данный момент изменяется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public abstract class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
    private final int position;

    public MyTextWatcher(final int position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        beforeTextChanged(s, start, count, after, position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        onTextChanged(s, start, before, count, position);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        afterTextChanged(s, position);
    }

    public abstract void afterTextChanged(Editable s, int position);

    public abstract void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count, int position);

    public abstract void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after, int position);

}
```

Comment: public void afterTextChanged(Editable s, int position) {
    results.get(position).put("mark", s.toString());
}
Сделал так. Но теперь такая проблема. Если допустим на экран помещается 6 элементов списка. Начинаю листать. Первый элемент уходит с экрана, в position значение 0, и он в первый элемент записывает значение из того элемента, который на экране создастся ( т.е. из 7-ого).

Comment: Потому что надо очищать EditTex, если значения нету в коллекции:
if (results.get(position).get("mark") != null) {
     viewHolder.etMark.setText(results.get(position).get("mark"));
} else {
     viewHolder.etMark.setText("");
}
//закрепляем textwatcher'ы

Comment: Теперь когда пытаюсь отредактировать 1-й элемент в первый раз, прокручиваю список вниз, возвращаюсь, значение старое. Меняю второй раз его же, прокручиваю вниз, в 7-й элемент(который первый создаётся) ставится фокус и записывается это же значение, прокручиваю назад, значение в 1-ом остаётся изменённое. Так же и наоборот, если 7-ой изменю, пролистаю вверх, в 1-ом будет значение из 7-ого.

Comment: Скорее всего это всё изза того что в один EditText добавляется несколько  TextWatcherов. Нужно перед каждым добавление TextWatcher удалять из него предыдущие с помощью метода removeTextChangedListener куда передается TextWatcher. Механизм TextChangedListener такой что он не использует один интерфейс, а все TextWatcherы кидает в массив, и потом каждый из них по очереди вызывает при определенном событии. Поэтому Вам нужно либо отказаться от ViewHolder паттерна, либо использовать вместо TextWatchera  
setOnFocusChangeListener() в котором при потере фокуса проверять изменились ли данные или нет.

Comment: Либо как то очищать EditText от предыдущего TextWatchera

Comment: Спасибо за подсказки, буду пробовать. Если есть какие-то похожие примеры, не могли бы поделиться ссылкой.